# Datatable Pagination pointing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, datatables

I am  developing a web application that having a datatable plugin.

I am fetching table rows as Datatable Dynamically with ajax.

Each row contains an edit button and delete button.

For Ex: when I switch to page 3 and click the edit button its gone to the edit page.

After submitting the page system will force to redirect to table list page.

On that time datatable showing from the first page in datatble. I want to show the 3 rd page.

How can I change this from page 3 ?

```
 var oTable = $('.dataTable').DataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      'iDisplayLength':5,
      "bSort": false,// disable sort options
      "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "_all" ],"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 6,7,8 ] }],
      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            $('td:eq(5)', nRow).addClass( "text-right" );
        },
      "ajax":{
        url :"get-model-datatble.php", // json datasource
        async:false,
        dataType:'json',
        type: "post", // method , by default get
      }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking... what is the specific error you are getting? what is the desired result you want?

Comment: When I reaching after edit window. I need to show the 3rd page as default... ?

Comment: When you go to edit page, send the source page number as a parameter too, and when you save your edit, use that page number argument to go to your desired page.

Comment: You want it to return to the 3rd page instead of the 1st page after the edit occurs? Correct? and @AbdullahShoaib is right.  We would need to see a lot more code to help you out though.

Comment: yes exaclty. I can pass as an argument and in redirect page its getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script

```
var oTable = $('.dataTable').DataTable();
oTable.fnPageChange(2,true);
```

Or

https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart

Add the displayStart option

```
 var oTable = $('.dataTable').DataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      'iDisplayLength':5,
       "displayStart": 20,
      "bSort": false,// disable sort options
      "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "_all" ],"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 6,7,8 ] }],
      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            $('td:eq(5)', nRow).addClass( "text-right" );
        },
      "ajax":{
        url :"get-model-datatble.php", // json datasource
        async:false,
        dataType:'json',
        type: "post", // method , by default get
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try  "displayStart": 20, working fine, see the updated answer

Comment: when I added "displayStart": 20, in my code. its showing the 3rd page.

Comment: can u please share your mail id ?

Comment: glad help it, can you accept my answer and vote it ?